# Log plot with 5 divisions

Tags: datasheet

I have some troubles with reading this
[datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/83787/tcst5250.pdf).

For example the plot

[image: Plot]

I know normal log and double log scales but the plots in this datasheet have only 4 divisions. Is it then 1,2,4,6,8,10?

Comment: Such sparse graphs will put a marker halfway between 1 and 10, and halfway between 10 and 100, for example. Those two markers, at half-a-decade, will be at 1*sqrt(10) and at 10*sqrt(10); rounding from 3.16 and from 31.6, the markers are at 3 and at 30. Does this help?

Answer (score 2):

Graph reproduced here, so people don't have to go looking

[image]

There's no line exactly halfway between 1 and 10, so 3 (a common approximation on logplots to 3.162) is not marked.

This suggests  the lines before and after the mid point are 2 and 4. Notice the first two divisions are the same width, so have the same ratio, which would support them being 2 and 4.

The next division is smaller, so it's not a factor of 2, but ignoring that and going for the next line, that appears to be the same factor of 2 distance, so is probably 8. It's quite close to 10, which sounds good.

The line between 4 and 8, and closer to 8? It's likely to be 6.

Measuring all the divisions and taking exponentials confirms (approximately) those guesses.

Comment: Notice the equi-distant 1-2, 2-4, 4-skipping6-8, intervals. And yes, the near_50% marker is missing.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few "conventions" of log scales.
The standard log scale plots single digit precision lines, showing ten divisions between decades.
The plots you're viewing follow a 1,2,4,6,8 sequence (five divisions between decades):
[image: 5-division log scale]

An even more coarse plot might follow a 1,2,5 sequence. Oscilloscopes often do this.

Sometimes, you even see a 1,3 sequence. Or a 1, 3.16 sequence...but that gets confusing, because it doesn't *look like* a log scale, it looks like a linear scale. The only way you can tell its logarithmic nature is by noticing the 1,10,100,1000 sequence of decades.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it seems to be 1,2,4,6,8,10 sequence based on distances taken from the graph.

You can confirm this yourself, just measure the distance between two 10's lines (*a*) and distance from the nearest lower 10's line to analyzed tic (*b*). Then respective multiplier is simply
$$
10^{\frac{b}{a}}
$$